# Multiple sharepoint list column validation in list settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-list-filter

I am new to SharePoint and Power Automate. I have to put multiple conditions in SharePoint list validation settings.

Example:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Unit Amount]),TRUE,[Unit Amount]=[PO Amount])
```

Which would validate Unit Amount against PO Amount if Unit Amount is not blank.

Similarly I need to validate few more columns before someone hits save.

Example:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([SP]),TRUE,[SP]=[MP])
```

How can I concatenate these conditions in the list settings - Validation settings.

Preferably, I required different messages for each validation but I figured that would not be possible.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: Sharepoint online with office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [AND function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-9ca21054-a466-477e-98bf-fc79e62afb3c) to concatenate multiple conditions. For example:

```
=AND(IF(ISBLANK([Unit Amount]),TRUE,[Unit Amount]=[PO Amount]),IF(ISBLANK([SP]),TRUE,[SP]=[MP]))
```

Besides, in list validation settings we can only have one message.

Comment: Thankyou. This worked.

Comment: If my anwer helps you, please accept it :)